# Typeform data into a dictionary

Tags: python, forms, typeform

I try to use import data from my typeform containing my own excercise data. The package `typeform` uses typeforms API to download the data. I want to put my responses in a dictionary so that I can use pandas to analyze the data.

The [package documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typeform/0.1.1) is short and it provides 6 rows of code on how to import the data. My first problem is that I get an error that I down't know how to handle

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

My second problem is that I'm not sure how to do a for loop over `.questions` and `.answers` `response` in order to build a dictionary. The documentation loops and prints the answers out, but I want the in a dictionary. I think I can start with an empty dictionary and use the append method.

Here is my modification of the code on the package documentation page:

```
import typeform

# set my parameters and download the form data
apikey = '07466391d081290e87a95868893868e6e55c73c3'
formid = 'xqBhCO'
form = typeform.Form(api_key=apikey, form_id=formid)

# Fetch all responses to the form with default options
responses = form.get_responses()
responses # I have 16 questions and 138 responses 

# Print '<question>: <answer>' for all responses to this form
for response in responses:
    for answer in response.answers:
        print '{question}: {answer}'.format(question=answer.question,
        answer=answer.answer)
```

Running this code produces the output:

```
  ... 
  Yoga: 1
  date: 2017-11-10
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 10: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

## Update

After reading typeforms API documentation I saw that I can use

```
https://api.typeform.com/v1/form/[typeform_UID]?key=[your_API_key]
```

In order to see the data, so for my case that is https://api.typeform.com/v1/form/xqBhCO?key=07466391d081290e87a95868893868e6e55c73c3 Hence if there is another package, more known/stable than `typeform` e.g. `beautifulsoup` maybe I could use that one to go from my responses to a nice pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The typeform package doesn't seem to work as intended in Python 2 - so this is typeforms fault.

The typeform package - and your example code - works in Python 3 however.

(Unicode string handling changed a lot in Python 3)

```
import typeform

# set my parameters and download the form data
apikey = '07466391d081290e87a95868893868e6e55c73c3'
formid = 'xqBhCO'
form = typeform.Form(api_key=apikey, form_id=formid)

# Fetch all responses to the form with default options
responses = form.get_responses()
responses # I have 16 questions and 138 responses 

# Print '<question>: <answer>' for all responses to this form
for response in responses:
    for answer in response.answers:
        print('{question}: {answer}'.format(question=answer.question,
        answer=answer.answer))
```